# Can I bind a Lambda Layer directly to a static ARN instead of a zip file

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, terraform

I want to use an AWS provided Layer in a Lamba function. In Terraform what is the preferred way to bind it? Also, can the ARN be bound directly to the Layers property of the module, bypassing the need for defining the layer?

```
resource "aws_lambdas_layer" "lambda_layer"{
    #filename = "python32-pandas.zip"
    layer_name= "aws-pandas-py38-layer"
    arn = "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxxxx:AWSSDKPandas-Python38:1" #? Is this valid
}

module "lambda_test" {
  source                    = "git::https://git.my-custom-aws-lambda.git"
  application               = var.application
  service                   = "${var.service}-test"
  file_path                 = "lambda_function.zip"
  publicly_accessible       = false
  data_classification       = "confidential"
  handler                   = "lambda_function.lambda_handler"
  runtime                   = "python3.8"
  tfs_releasedefinitionname = ""
  tfs_releasename           = "0"
  vpc_enabled               = true
  vpc_application_tag       = "aws-infra"
  promote                   = true
  rollback                  = false
  create_cwl_group          = true
  cwl_prefix                = "my-project"
  create_cwl_subscription   = false
  #Could layers an arn?      
  layers                    = [aws_lambda_layer_version.lambda_layer.arn]
  timeout                   = 600  ####10 mins
  memory_size               = 1024 #### 1GB 
  environment = {    
    variables = {
      destination_bucket_name = "us-east-1-my-sbx-${terraform.workspace}"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A bit of context is missing. What is in the module? Is it a custom one or you are using a module someone else has created? Can you add the Lambda function part of the module to the question?

Comment: @Marrko E 5 - Yes, the module points to a git based terraform lambda with additional facets. I am attempting to convert the pandas layer from an internally maintained zip file-based layer to one AWS makes available.

Comment: Well what does the `layers` variable in the module map to?

Comment: @MarkoE - Sorry, typo. It maps to the aws_lambdas_layer.lambda_layer resource above it. I attempted a plan and got this error -> Can't configure a value for "arn": its value will be decided automatically based on the result of applying this configuration. I will try the file name or specifying the arn in the layer.

Comment: There is no resource actually named `aws_lambdas_layer`. What you probably want is the Lambda layer data source: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/lambda_layer_version.

Comment: @MarkoE - Sorry that was another typo, the layer was bound to aws_lambda_layer_version.lambda_layer.arn. Anyway, thanks for the help. I will attempt to wade my way through it. I thought there was an easy way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh! The layers property is an [array]. Minor lapse of reading comprehension on my part :/

The solution is to bind the layers to an array of ["arns"] pointing to the aws or custom arn(s).

```
layers                    = ["arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:336392948345:layer:AWSSDKPandas-Python39:1"]
```